# How can you get the latest EmbeddedDocument objects with MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm trying to do a query to get the latest comments that have been posted to any Post, but can't get it right. I basically want to show an activity list of all comments posted on the website.

I'm using flask, mongodb with mongo-engine.

Here are my models:

```
class Post(db.Document):
    slug = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    body = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    comments = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Comment'))

class Comment(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    message = db.StringField(required=True)
    author = db.ReferenceField(User, dbref=True)
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. 
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema design for that particular usecase is poor.  You should store Comments as a separate Document and then you can query the data in the way that you need efficiently.

Alternatively, you could denormalise and store the latest x comments in a separate document / collection.  You would have to manually manage this collection though.

The mongodb docs has a good section on [data modeling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/) which might be helpful.

Comment: Might be a poor schema but the Flask Mongoengine docs and demos on the internet use something very similar. Also, you do not answer the question.

Comment: I thought my second sentence answered the question - basically store the comments in their own collection.  That means that you can query the comments effectively.  

I even offered another idea using this schema but adding another latest comments collection.  Providing two solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`EmbeddedDocumentField` means that this document just part of own document like dictionary. So you can get all posts with all comments, then you can get all comments and sort it. Or you can make `comments` as list of `ReferenceField` and `Comment` as `Documetn`. Or you can write own mongo function that will do it.

Perhaps pymongo allow get part of list, but I don't know how. However as I know mongoengoe doesn't allow it out the box.